# insert statement in oracle without using user defined function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have table `employees` with columns `eno, ename, job, sal, comm`
and the query like

```
INSERT a new employee
eno as 7787,
ename as 'abc',
job  as 'salesman'
sal as 2000,
comm as tax amount
```

this **tax** is the function like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  tax
( p_sal employees.sal%type
)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
v_tax employees.sal%type;
BEGIN
v_tax:= CASE
        WHEN SAL> 4000 THEN SAL * 0.33
        WHEN SAL >2500 THEN SAL *0.25
        WHEN SAL >1500 THEN SAL * 0.20
        ELSE 0
        END;
RETURN v_tax
END tax;
```

At the INSERT statement I can't use function `tax` for the column `comm`.
Is there any other method to do this, or how can this be best achieved?

Answer (score 2):

When you say

> I can't use function `tax` for the column `comm`

do you mean you're not allowed to use this function, or you can't figure out how to use it?

Assuming the latter, I don't see why you shouldn't be able to use a function in an INSERT statement.  You have, however, got the syntax of the INSERT statement completely wrong.

Try

```
INSERT INTO employee (eno, ename, job, sal, comm)
  VALUES (7787, 'abc', 'salesman', 2000, tax(2000));
```

I don't know where `amount` in your INSERT statement comes from, but given that your function takes  a parameter called `p_sal`, I'm guessing it's applied to the value in the column `sal`.